# Migrate umbraco media folder to another server

Tags: media, umbraco, migrate

I need to migrate my media folder to another server.
That's what I have now:
http://mysite.com/media/111/picture.jpg

That's what I want:
http://newserver.mysite.com/media/111/picture.jpg

But I want to use the umbraco backoffice of mysite.com/umbraco/

How can I do that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I seriously don't understand how this is offtopic? :S

Answer (score 4):

If I am understanding your requirement correctly, you want to move the media file somewhere else on the file system.

You have two options:

1. move the folder to the new location on the file system, then add a new folder in IIS, call it media, and point it to the new folder.
2. In the web.config, add a new appsetting called UmbracoMediaPath. Depending on what your version of Umbraco is, you might need to do this in the /config/FileSystemProviders.config file instead.

More information [here](http://our.umbraco.org/wiki/reference/webconfig/additional-umbraco-specific-appsettings) and [here](http://our.umbraco.org/forum/getting-started/installing-umbraco/15541-Different-location-for-Media-folder)

Comment: option 2 will open a can of worms as you need to alter values in the database for media that has been uploaded before the change.